# VS 2008 - Procedure to ship C#/WPF solution to ensure compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, collaboration

I am attempting to collaborate on a C#/WPF project with another developer remotely via e-mail; and although the code compiles perfectly when it leaves, my collaborator has not been able to compile the code on his side.  We are both using VS 2008 Version 9.  This is the first time trying to work with someone else on an application and I was hoping that someone would advise me if there are any suggestions to obtain and ensure compatibility between the two of us?  Additionally, is there a recommended procedure to prepare the solution for shipment (ie. just zip up the solution folder? export the application? etc.)?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a central source control server with something like SVN, GIT or Mercurial, this way you do not have to transfer the project by email, you just commit (and in case of GIT push) the changes and the other can merge them easily with his modifications.

Possible Problems are:

- Different installed .NET Frameworks.
- Referenced Assemblies might be installed at another path.
- Different Assembly-Versions.
- Hardcoded Paths in project settings.

Comment: Thank you dbemerlin.  Great suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Our most common issue with WPF and Visual Studio was one of us having .NET 3.5 and the other .NET 3.5 SP1...  Try installing the service pack on both machines.

You could also tell us what compile errors you are getting.

Comment: Chris - 
Great heads up.  Thank you.
Bill